# CPU usage reaches 100% when I plug-in AC

Tags: 18.04, cpu

Recently I've found a problem, when I plug-in AC, CPU usage reaches 80% - 100% and I'll find a lot of lag in the system.

**Before connecting AC:**
[[htop & top 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqYWM.png)]

**After connecting AC:**
[[htop & top 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hune.png)]

Comment: Removed `kubuntu` tag. It doesn't seem relevant or is it?

Comment: I've removed the `kubuntu` tag from another question of yours as well. Using tags such as `kubuntu` or `lubuntu` or `xubuntu` is useful only when the respective desktop environment is in use.